# Build an adjacency matrix from distances between cosmological objects

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I'm probing into the [Illustris](https://www.tng-project.org/) API, and gathering information from a specific cosmos simulation, for a given redshift value.

This is how I request the api:

```
import requests

baseUrl = 'http://www.tng-project.org/api/'
    
def get(path, params=None):
    # make HTTP GET request to path
    headers = {"api-key":"my_key"}
    r = requests.get(path, params=params, headers=headers)

    # raise exception if response code is not HTTP SUCCESS (200)
    r.raise_for_status()

    if r.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json':
        return r.json() # parse json responses automatically
    
    if 'content-disposition' in r.headers:
        filename = r.headers['content-disposition'].split("filename=")[1]
        with open(f'sky_dataset/simulations/{filename}', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        return filename # return the filename string
    return r
```

And below I get the star coordinates for a given subhalo in this particular simulation. Note that -if I'm doing it right- distances have already been converted from `ckpc/h` to `physical kpc`.

Physical coordinates are the actual distances you would measure between them if you froze space and started laying out measuring rods:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

simulation_id = 100
redshift = 0.57
subhalo_id = 99

scale_factor = 1.0 / (1+redshift)
little_h = 0.704

params = {'stars':'Coordinates,GFM_Metallicity'}

url = "http://www.tng-project.org/api/Illustris-1/snapshots/z=" + str(redshift) + "/subhalos/" + str(subhalo_id)
sub = get(url) # get json response of subhalo properties
saved_filename = get(url + "/cutout.hdf5",params) # get and save HDF5 cutout file

with h5py.File(f'sky_dataset/simulations/{saved_filename}') as f:
    # NOTE! If the subhalo is near the edge of the box, you must take the periodic boundary into account! (we ignore it here)
    dx = f['PartType4']['Coordinates'][:,0] - sub['pos_x']
    dy = f['PartType4']['Coordinates'][:,1] - sub['pos_y']
    dz = f['PartType4']['Coordinates'][:,2] - sub['pos_z']
    
    rr = np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)
    rr *= scale_factor/little_h # ckpc/h -> physical kpc

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
    with mpl.rc_context(rc={'axes3d.grid': True}):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

        # Plot the values
        ax.scatter(dx, dy, dz)
        ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
        ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
        ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')
    plt.show()
```

The above plots:

[image]

as requested by one comment, I print dy, dy, dz truncated examples:

```
dx = [ 2.63370612e-01  3.48350511e-01 -1.23379511e-02 ...  6.63767411e+00
  1.32910697e+01  8.75469902e+00]

dy = [  0.33889825   0.21808108   0.50170807 ...   8.95542985  -9.84251952
 -16.38661054]

dz = [ -0.26469788  -0.10382767  -0.16625317 ...  -4.84708218 -13.77888398
  10.42730599]
```

---

My aim is to build a connectivity network for this system, starting with an square (simetrical) adjacency matrix, whereby any two stars (or vertices) are connected if they lie within the linking length *l* of *1.2 Mpc*, that is:

```
Aij = 1 if rij ≤ l, otherwise 0
```

where *rij* is the distance between the two vertices, *i* and *j*.

How can I get this adjacency matrix, based on my linking length?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment and advices. I thought I had done that already. But double thanks, anyway. Noted.

Comment: Hey, I urge you to format your apikeys out and to request new ones or people might steal them.

Comment: Could you post some sample data from `dx`, `dy`, and `dz`? In the meantime, take a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.radius_neighbors_graph.html#sklearn.neighbors.radius_neighbors_graph

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler sure, please refer to my edit. sample data is truncated. But I could arrange to give you the full arrays, if you wish. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [sklearn.neighbors.radius_neighbors_graph](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.radius_neighbors_graph.html#sklearn.neighbors.radius_neighbors_graph) and your example data:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import radius_neighbors_graph

# Your example data in runnable format
dx = np.array([2.63370612e-01, 3.48350511e-01, -1.23379511e-02, 
               6.63767411e+00, 1.32910697e+01,  8.75469902e+00])
dy = np.array([0.33889825,  0.21808108,   0.50170807, 
               8.95542985, -9.84251952, -16.38661054])
dz = np.array([-0.26469788,  -0.10382767, -0.16625317, 
               -4.84708218, -13.77888398, 10.42730599])

# Build a coordinate matrix with columns x, y, z, with one star per row
X = np.column_stack([dx, dy, dz])

print(X)
[[ 2.63370612e-01  3.38898250e-01 -2.64697880e-01]
 [ 3.48350511e-01  2.18081080e-01 -1.03827670e-01]
 [-1.23379511e-02  5.01708070e-01 -1.66253170e-01]
 [ 6.63767411e+00  8.95542985e+00 -4.84708218e+00]
 [ 1.32910697e+01 -9.84251952e+00 -1.37788840e+01]
 [ 8.75469902e+00 -1.63866105e+01  1.04273060e+01]]

# Find the neighbours of each star, restricted to distance lower than radius=1.2
C = radius_neighbors_graph(X, 1.2)

# C is the connectivity matrix in Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) format. 
# For demonstration purposes, convert CSR matrix to dense representation 
# as a numpy matrix
C.todense()

matrix([[0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

For your example data of six stars, the connectivity matrix shows:

- Star 0 (row 0) is within 1.2 distance units (kpc) of Stars 1 and 2
- Stars 1 and 2 are within 1.2 kpc of each other

(You asked for a linking distance of 1.2 Mpc, which would correspond to `radius=1200`. For demo purposes, here I used `radius=1.2`, corresponding to 1.2 **k**pc, because all six stars are within 1.2 Mpc of each other, which would have resulted in a rather boring connectivity matrix.)

Comment: beautiful solution...I had thought of using KNN, hardcoding arbitrary 'n' neighbors, but using radius here is the catch. nicely done

Comment: Glad this helped! Your question taught me a few things about numpy (`column_stack`) and scikit-learn, so thank you - and good luck with the analysis!